# SQL Server backup from VB.NET not generating backup file, file not shown in drive

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, backup, sql-server-2012-express

I am using VB.NET with SQL Server 2012 Express in a software.

I provided facility to take a backup of a database from application itself with following code

```
Dim con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Master;User id=sa;password=admin;")
con.Open()
Dim str as string="backup database OFFICEMANAGEMENT to disk='C:\OM.bak'"
Dim cmd as new SqlCommand(str,con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
con.Close()
```

When above code is run, no backup file gets created, and also no error is shown.

If I run the `backup` command with T-SQL in the SQL Server Management Studio, the backup file is successfully created.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: You never ***open*** the connection - try `con.Open()` **before** the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` call

Comment: Added the code, but still backup file is not generated. Its works from TSQL in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code as follows

1. Your connection should be open before execution command.
2. T-SQL statement to backup the database should contain 'WITH INIT' keywords. If you execute your code multiple time, your BAK file will continue to grow.

   So, try this one

   ```
   Using con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;User id=sa;password=admin;")

       con.Open()

       Dim str As String = "backup database OFFICEMANAGEMENT to disk='C:\TMP\OM.bak' WITH INIT"

       Using cmd = New SqlCommand(str, con)
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       End Using

       con.Close()

   End Using
   ```

Comment: Its not about opening a connection, backup file is still not generated after adding that line.

Comment: And there is no exceptions? Very strange. Try changing the path. Put the backup file somewhere else.

Comment: Tried creating files in D drive and E drive also. I doubt if its a permission kind of issue.